# Combining distinct, group by and order by in complicated HQL queries

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, grails, groovy, hql

Actually I have been trying to use group by , order by in HQL queries whole day yet no result has been found. I have researched a lot in different articles and stackoverflow's questions answers and gone through many of them and tried but none of the answers could answer in my scenario.

I am writing a query that basically should fetch unique values but has joining and more as shown in the code below in groovy syntax.

```
String query = "select o ${queryAndParams?.queryString}"
```

Here, `queryAndParams?.queryString` will be generated based on the options we pass as params which has no problem.

One of the queries from the log is

```
select o  from RequestOffer o inner join o.request r 
     inner join r.event e inner join o.offerParts as rop
     inner join o.statusLogs lg where lg.dateCreated between :fromDate 
     and :toDate and o.status = :approvedStatus  and o.deletedDate is null and 
     r.removeFromAdminReport = false and e.removeFromAdminReport = false  and 
     e.isTemplate is false and r.isTemplate is false  group by o.id, e.fromDate order by 
     e.fromDate + age(min(rop.dateTimeFrom) , '1970-01-01 00:00') desc
```

This query is fine except it is giving duplicating and for some reasons I want to filter out explicitly in query level [while fetching  from DB].
It would have been not that difficult but due to `order by  e.fromDate + age(min(rop.dateTimeFrom) , '1970-01-01 00:00')`
I am not being able to properly implement.

I tried `select distinct o from RequestOffer o ....` and it doesn't work as select doesn't have `e.fromDate + age(min(rop.dateTimeFrom)`
Also when wrting `elect distinct o, e.fromDate + age(min(rop.dateTimeFrom)  from RequestOffer o ....` also doesn't work as it is searching distinct for both.

I somehow noticed that pure PostgreSQL query in my console working and has syntax

```
select distinct on(o) o from request_offer o inner join request r on r.id = o.request_id 
inner join event e on r.event_id = e.id
inner join request_offer_part rop on o.id = rop.offer_id
inner join request_offer_status_log lg on lg.offer_id = o.id where lg.date_created 
between '2021-03-01' and '2022-03-07' and o.status = 'APPROVED'
and o.deleted_date is null and
r.remove_from_admin_report = false and e.remove_from_admin_report = false
and e.is_template is false and r.is_template is false
group by o.id, e.from_date order by o, e.from_date + 
age(min(rop.date_time_from) ,'1970- 
01-01 00:00') desc;
```

This seems to work fine but it isn't supported in HQL.
I've been somehow stuck due to this and would appreciate any guidance or code snippets.

Comment: You can change your query get better performance, using EXISTS clause instead JOIN. In this way you don't need about group by and / or distinct, because the main query has built only with one table.

Comment: @JoeTaras there are too many queries to modify if I want to go that way as ```${queryAndParams?.queryString}``` has different subqueries in different modules. I am searching for a solution if I can apply distinct syntax to get unique value ```select [distinct here somehow ...] ``` but getting confused a lot.